# Is there a way to hide debug logging of a package in Visual Studio C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, logging, blazor, opc-ua

I am writing a DotNetCore 3.1 Blazer Server Side application. One of the required modules is an OPC UA Client wrapper dll I wrote around OPC Foundation's NetStandard implementation. This wrapper does not log anything. All logging appears to be done by the OPC Foundation.

We make around 25 read/write operations per second. Each operations logs data like so:

```
8/2/2021 10:42:03.808 Read Completed. RequestHandle=204, PendingRequestCount=0
8/2/2021 10:42:04.501 Read Called. RequestHandle=208, PendingRequestCount=1
8/2/2021 10:42:04.503 Bytes written: 136
```

This spams the debug log, a problem for obvious reasons.

Ideally I would like to make my dll not log these operations, but a solution to mute them in Visual Studio 2019 would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure what the OPCF NetStandard stack is logging by calling `Utils.SetTraceMask()`

| **Level** | Value | Usage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| None | 0x0 | Not a useable level for logging itself, just for user to deactivate logging |
| All | 0x7FFFFFFF | Output all messages |
| Security | 0x200 | Basic Messages related to security |
| ExternalSystem | 0x100 | Not used within stack |
| StartStop | 0x80 | Messages related to application initialization or shutdown |
| OperationDetail | 0x40 | Detailed Messages for each operation |
| Operation | 0x20 | Basic Messages for each operation |
| ServiceDetail | 0x10 | Detailed Messages for service calls |
| Service | 0x8 | Basic Messages for service calls |
| StackTrace | 0x4 | Output stack traces |
| Information | 0x2 | Output informational messages |
| Error | 0x1 | Output error messages |

*Note*: to use the stack logging it is required to call `Utils.SetTraceOutput(Utils.TraceOutput.DebugAndFile)` and `Utils.SetTraceLog(null, false)` because up to now, the stack don’t support TraceOutput.DebugOnly logging and logging into file is unusable (open, modify and close trace file for each log entry).

The good news is that the team works on improving the tracing/logging (see [UA-.NETStandard#1262](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/issues/1262).